# Create PDF with an include file - wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, pdf

I want to get the content of a webpage and create a PDF with it. I need to use the php buffering to get my page and then I render into a PDF with wkhtmltopdf but the error displayed is :

> Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError

```
$commission_pk = $_POST['commission'];
ob_start();

$inc =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test.php';

include($inc);

$contents = ob_get_contents();


ob_end_clean();

  $sql_client = query;
if($result = $db->query($sql_client)){
 if($result->num_rows > 0){
   if(class_exists('\mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf')){
     $pdf = new \mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf($contents);
     if (!$pdf->send('Facture N°'.$commission_pk)) {
       echo $pdf->getError();
     }
   }
}
```

The message error say that I have no content but if I echo `$contents` it displays the page that I want. Maybe the type of the content isn't take into consideration by wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 0):

More than likely your `$contents` contains some references to files that cannot be fetched by wkhtmltopdf, maybe protocol-less URLs or relative paths to images or css/js.

Hard to say without seeing said html but if you don't care about those errors you can try the `ignoreWarnings` option: https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf#wrapper-options